# BSOD: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

recently I've been encountering BSODs on my Windows 7 64-bit SP1 computer and need help to resolve the problem.

These BSODs usually happen when my computer is idle for a while (about a couple hours).

The most recent Minidump file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIGjkREqeqT0FnMzNVdUVYMTA/edit?usp=sharing.

Using WinDbg to debug the file shows this:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver is causing an inconsistent power state.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 0000000000000258, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: fffffa8006a92730, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: fffff80000b9c3d0

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  4

FAULTING_THREAD:  fffffa8006a92730

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CODE_CORRUPTION

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

LOCK_ADDRESS:  fffff80003cdbda0 -- (!locks fffff80003cdbda0)

Resource @ nt!PiEngineLock (0xfffff80003cdbda0)    Available

WARNING: SystemResourcesList->Flink chain invalid. Resource may be corrupted, or already deleted.


WARNING: SystemResourcesList->Blink chain invalid. Resource may be corrupted, or already deleted.

1 total locks

PNP_TRIAGE: 
    Lock address  : 0xfffff80003cdbda0
    Thread Count  : 0
    Thread address: 0x0000000000000000
    Thread wait   : 0x0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80003acd5f2 to fffff80003adaa8a

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`03578480 fffff800`03acd5f2 : fffffa80`06a92730 fffffa80`06a92730 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSwapContext+0x7a
fffff880`035785c0 fffff800`03ade99f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1d2
fffff880`03578650 fffff800`03b98957 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
fffff880`035786f0 fffff800`03ea351e : fffff800`03cdbb60 fffffa80`0e455740 fffffa80`0d553270 fffffa80`0e4558e8 : nt!PnpDeviceCompletionQueueRemoveCompletedRequest+0x37
fffff880`03578750 fffff800`03ea37a4 : fffffa80`0e455740 fffffa80`0a78004d fffffa80`0a785970 00000000`00000001 : nt!PnpStartDeviceNode+0x16e
fffff880`035787e0 fffff800`03ec6eb6 : fffffa80`0e455740 fffffa80`0a785970 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!PipProcessStartPhase1+0x74
fffff880`03578810 fffff800`03ec7448 : fffff800`03cd9720 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 fffff800`03d42258 : nt!PipProcessDevNodeTree+0x296
fffff880`03578a80 fffff800`03bda827 : 00000001`00000003 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!PiProcessReenumeration+0x98
fffff880`03578ad0 fffff800`03ae1261 : fffff800`03bda500 fffff800`03dcec01 fffffa80`06a92700 fffff800`03c7d2d8 : nt!PnpDeviceActionWorker+0x327
fffff880`03578b70 fffff800`03d7373a : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`06a92730 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`069e0890 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x111
fffff880`03578c00 fffff800`03ac88e6 : fffff880`03389180 fffffa80`06a92730 fffff880`033940c0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`03578c40 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`03579000 fffff880`03573000 fffff880`03576a20 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xfffffa8006a92730 ; kb

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff80003adadb2 - nt!SwapContext_PatchXSave+2
    [ 01:21 ]
    fffff80003adae96 - nt!SwapContext_PatchXRstor+2 (+0xe4)
    [ 09:29 ]
2 errors : !nt (fffff80003adadb2-fffff80003adae96)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  ONE_BIT_LARGE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT_LARGE

Followup: memory_corruption
```

Using BlueScreenView to debug shows this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIGjkREqeqc29jYXlsS29yZEk/edit?usp=sharing

Given that it could be a driver issue I tried running Driver Verifier but my computer kept on crashing at the Windows Boot Screen. No minidump files were created upon crash.

It would be great if anyone could help me solve this problem.

Thanks all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff80003adadb2 - nt!SwapContext_PatchXSave+2
    [ 01:21 ]
    fffff80003adae96 - nt!SwapContext_PatchXRstor+2 (+0xe4)
    [ 09:29 ]
2 errors : !nt (fffff80003adadb2-fffff80003adae96)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption
```

This shows that your Windows Kernel is corrupted in at parts. This can happen due to bad RAM (corruption in the RAM) or that the file itself is damaged on the HDD.

So you should run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) to check the RAM, if this is fine, run `chkdsk /f` to fix NTFS file system issues and run [sfc /scannow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us) to detect ad repair corupted Windows files.

Comment: thanks for the reply (: I ran chkdsk also, it came up with no errors. SFC doesn't work on my computer (tinkered around with a few explorer files to change the ui a bit, perhaps that why it doesn't work :\ but these files shouldn't impact the core system). I'll try out memtest and see what goes (:

Comment: what is not working when you run sfc /scannow?

Comment: it returns with an error at about 10% verification. I don't have a windows 7 repair disk.

Comment: witch error? post a picture.

Comment: ran chkdsk /f /r and got this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIGjkREqeqMnlETllERUFIV00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here's the sfc /scannow error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIGjkREqeqVi1oVVNsdnAxLU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, this issue can happen when you use a 64Bit Windows and run sfc from a 32Bit cmd.exe and if you have disabled the "Windows modules installer" service.

Comment: there's a 64-bit cmd? that's new. I'll try out on 64-bit cmd (once I google how to activate it) edit: it seems I've been using 64-bit cmd for everything...including sfc. windows module installer has been started normally.

Comment: memtest86+ ran for 6 hours (3 tests) and came up with no errors. will run it through the night later, but I don't think there'll be any errors. any other possible solutions to the problem?

Comment: upload the CBS folder from C:\Windows\logs (copy the folder to the desktop, zip and upload it to a cloud service and post a link here)

Comment: here's the CBS log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIGjkREqeqU29BeF9oU3l1d00/edit?usp=sharing running memtest86+ met with 718 errors on the third pass. (ran on dual channel) however I found another dump file titled memory.dmp at C:\Windows and it cited ntkrnlmp.exe as the cause of the BSOD. pretty big file (700mb) so I won't upload it. I suspect its something to do with my kernel, got the W7 ISO ready for a repair install if necessary already.

Comment: if the RAMtest shows 718 the RAM is the issue. Test each RAM module on its own until you find the broken one. Sfc fails because of missing permissions (STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED). have you started the cmd.exe as admin?

Comment: yep, ran the 64-bit cmd as admin. running windows in safe mode and running sfc there also gives the same problem. I can't access startup repair for some reason too (tried using it a couple times to try and fix sfc, then I somehow couldn't access it) as for the memtest86+ results...I'm not sure about this, but the debug file did mention that it was a DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Comment: test each RAM module on its own until you find the buggy RAM.

Comment: so it definitely has to be a problem with the RAM?

Comment: yes it is the RAM